# How to map Deployment probes to target group health check for AWS EKS?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, kubernetes-deployment

```
$ kubectl version --short
Client Version: v1.20.2
Server Version: v1.19.6-eks-49a6c0
```

I have the following Deployment manifest as part of a Helm chart, which also includes a `ingress.yaml` file that creates a resulting ALB with listener rules, with the HTTPS listener rule pointing to a target group, which is also created, along with the target. However, the target's health check's path does NOT contain the `/manage/health` path I have in the manifest, it's simply `/`, which is of course wrong. How can I map the resulting target's health check to the `liveliness` probe below?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: stats-service
  namespace: my-system
  labels:
    app: stats-service
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: stats-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: stats-service
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: stats-service
        image: 0123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/stats-service:3.12.1
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 5000
          protocol: TCP
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /manage/health
            port: 5000
          failureThreshold: 3
          periodSeconds: 10
```

Update: Actually, none of the probe's values are mapped to the target health check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am totally off-base on this one. The Deployment probes are for "pods" and not the actual target in the resulting target group of my infrastructure. Health check settings for the actual containers, i.e., targets in a target group, are defined in the [Ingress annotations](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/guide/ingress/annotations/#healthcheck-path).